# Вывод с камеры готовых изображений в ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, камера

Нужна помощь с вводом изображений в `ListView`. Есть готовый код для создания снимков и сохранение их в `ImageView`. Но я не знаю как сделать что бы после создания изображение они выводились списком в `ListView`.

Код камеры:

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    DatabaseHelper sqlHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ListView listphoto;
    Button bsphoto;
    SimpleCursorAdapter Adapter;


    final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1;
    final int PIC_CROP = 2;
    private Uri picUri;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment2, container, false);

        bsphoto = view.findViewById(R.id.bsphoto);

        sqlHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        db = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase();

//        Adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(view.getContext(), R.layout.activity_fragment2,
//                new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()),
//                new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PHOTO},
//                new int[]{R.id.imageViewPhoto});

//        listphoto = view.findViewById(R.id.listViewCollectionPhoto);
//        listphoto.setAdapter(Adapter);

        bsphoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    String errorMessage = "ERROR";
//                    Toast toast = Toast
//                            .makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
//                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == PIC_CROP) {
                picUri = data.getData();
                performCrop();
            }else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST ) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");

                ImageView picView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pic);
                picView.setImageBitmap(thePic);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

В коде есть закомментированные мои безуспешные попытки это сделать.

```
Adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(view.getContext(), R.layout.activity_fragment2,
new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()),
new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PHOTO},
new int[]{R.id.imageViewPhoto});

listphoto = view.findViewById(R.id.listViewCollectionPhoto);
listphoto.setAdapter(Adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо ListView, используйте RecyclerView. Для него нужно создать адаптер, например такой

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Bitmap> mData = new ArraList<>();

public void setImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
   mData.add(bitmap);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
// recyclerview_row - нужно также создать, ниже будет пример
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

// вставляем картинку в каждый imageview из списка
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String bitmap = mData.get(position);
    holder.myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

// тут инициализируем imageview из recyclerview_row
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView myImageView;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

}
```

Вот xml recyclerview_row

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Далее в вашем Fragment2 инициализируете RecyclerView вставляете в него адаптер

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvAnimals);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

После чего например в onActivityResult у вас или где угодно, можно вызвать

```
adapter.setImage(bitmap)
```

И будете по одному битмапу добавлять в список. Можно в адаптере сделать похожий на setImage(Bitmap bitmap), но, например со списком, типа

```
public void setImageList(List<Bitmap> bitmaps) {
   mData.clear();
   mData.addAll(bitmaps);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

И можно целым списком вставить битмапы

Comment: Спасибо, сработало. Но пришлось чутка изменить ваш код